# Magento 2 show product by attributes programmatically

Tags: magento2, category-listing

I want to show the product in the category (Product listing page) with pre-define product attribute custom attributes.

Right now it is showing all product. But I want to show only those product which has product type (Product attribute) saleable.

I don't know how to do that as I am new in Magento 2.

Comment: How to check a product  is `Saleable`?

Comment: Admin will set product type (Product attribute) as saleable.